I can't send data through fluent-bit to AWS OpenSearch
I am doing a project that tries to send information in a json file through fluent-bit to AWS OpenSearch, this is my configuration file in fluent-bit, I have already looked at a lot of official documentation on the fluent-bit and AWS page and I can not solve it, I'm desperate and my hair has fallen out.
[SERVICE]
Flush         1
Log_Level     info
Daemon        on
[INPUT]
Name          tail
Path          /home/file.json
Parser        json
Tag           amazon-opensearch
[OUTPUT]
Name                opensearch
Match               amazon-opensearch
Host                https://this-is-my-secret-url.es.amazonaws.com
Port                443
AWS_Auth            on
AWS_Service_Name    aoss
AWS_Role_ARN        arn:aws:es:us-east-1:00000000:domain/opensearch
AWS_Profile         default
Index               fluent-bit
Type                logs
he intentado cambiar de parametros en fluent bit, me gustaria que se enviara la informacion a opensearch

I would suggest reformatting your question to put the configs in code blocks so that we can read it properly.
I think we need some more info to help here
Can you share the logs from fluentbit, do they give any clue as to why it is failing?
What does the access policy for your Opensearch cluster look like? What does the security group for your OS cluster look like, does it allow traffic on port 443 from the IPs where fluentbit is running?

Can you try removing https:// from your config? I was trying a similar config with ECS to opensearch. removing https:// prefix fixed my issue.
